# How can I match the FET's input and output impedance?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, impedance-matching, microwave

I'm designing a FET mixer, so I have to match the FET's input and output to in and out port's impedance(50 ohm). I don't have the S-parameters, but I can set wide range of parameters(GS-resistance, DS-reisitance,capacitance, drain resistance, etc) of the FET. I think i should calculate the FET's input and output impedances for the  matching. How can I do that, knowing the mentioned parameters?

Comment: You might want to review the topology of typical implementations for such a thing, rather than trying to "wing it" uninformed by tradition.

Comment: _"I have to match the FET's input and output to in and out port's impedance(50 ohm)"_ - why?

Comment: Bruce Abbott: To achieve the maximum transducer gain, it's called conjugate matching. With lumped elements at low freqs, and with shunt and series transmission lines at the microwave band.

Comment: There are several examples for this in Pozar: microwave engineering, but those are don't explain how to carry out  this in CAD software. I know it seems a dumb problem, but I've just started designing circuits, I don't have any experience.

Answer (score -1):

You also need to include any BOND WIRES in the packages.

And ESD diodes may consume 50% of your energy, causing a 3 dB worse noise_figure.

Thus a successful "matching" requires knowing all the details of physical design.